# Bind in code behind (C++/CX)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have this xaml:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Height="{Binding MyCount}" />
```

I would like to bind using my C++/CX code behind instead. In WinJS I could do this:

```
datacontext.bind("MyCount", function () { MyRectangle.Height = MyCount; });
```

Is there an equivalent in C++/CX?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx) object and wire it up in code-behind.

```
Binding^ b = ref new Binding();
b->Mode = BindingMode::OneTime;
b->Source = MyCount;
MyRectangle->SetBinding(FrameworkElement::HeightProperty, b);
```

Comment: That's good - although what I was really after was some way to have a function/lambda execute when the bound-to property updates. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to skip binding and just handle property change notifications? MyCount can be a property and will use the normal property update system. You can set the BindingMode to OneWay or TwoWay as needed. If you bind to your own property instead of to the rectangle's height then your property would get the notifications

Comment: I'd like to call `Windows::UI::Xaml::VisualStateManager::GoToState(control, "StateName", true);` when MyCount updates. That way I can change a bunch of properties, with predefined transitions and everything. I'd imagined I'd be able to do that by having a callback fire when the property changed.